# Approaches for testing huge data files in text format

Tags: automated-testing, python, quality-assurance, database

My current assignment requires me to test data in a large number of text files ~ 200, usually ranging from 1GB to 20GB.
The data is in the same schema with coordinates.

As of now, the approach is to load these files in a database (PostgreSQL) and then fire test cases using Python.
Running a test on all the files (~80 GB) takes anywhere around 7/8 hours.

Even though the process is majorly automated, there are few drawbacks, namely a lack of proper reporting and manual intervention.

I want to optimise and improve this process.

Is the above approach is the best way of testing data?
Are there better ways to do this?

What are the approaches you guys use to test data?

Can data languages like R / Scala be useful for this kind of testing?

Looking for suggestions and pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve ? you can solve performance issues by moving to C and having better hardware, or by using distributed computing and storage like Hadoop.

Comment: 8 hours to process 80GB of data seems a long time. **Did you identify the bottlenecks?** (by profiling) Is it comparing parsed data against some "golden" pattern, and bottleneck is to access the "golden" value? Is bottleneck some calculation - can you make it faster? Changing to R will not make it faster if R will be doing same slow calls.  **Don't guess - measure.**

Comment: Do you have baseline files? If so, you may be better on a simple comparison so that if the test file and the baseline file are the same, you don't need to inspect any closer.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Validate the data is correct/meets some format?  Where is the data coming from?  What are you validating it separately?

Comment: @Rsf Time is not the problem here, it can easily be reduced by using distributed systems. The problem which I want to solve is about the approach I use. Is it the smartest way?

Comment: @KatePaulk Yes we do have baseline files, they serve as first level of validations.

Comment: @KevinMcKenzie We have to ensure that the data is in a set format. The tests are designed accordingly.

Comment: The basic issue is that I want to know if the process which I use, that is, dump files in a database and shoot queries, is the best way to test huge data files? or are there any smarter strategies?

Comment: I'm not completely sure this is the appropriate place for this question, as you're doing data validation, not software validation, and performance/best practices of data processing tools might be better asked in other places that cater more to data scientists, but that said . . . 

I think you need to decide what problem you're trying to solve.  You say you aren't time constrained; are you interested doing better reporting/error recovery?  Something like spark would make it easier to shard the data processing, I suspect.

Comment: What is the file structure? And your current logic/algorithm you are using to validate with CODE?

Comment: Please share your algorithm logic in a bit more detail so that people can suggest you more specific algorithm tunning solutions.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is not another tool/ framework or language but a better algorithm.

Comment: This appears to be a traditional transaction data validation not testing.  if it is testing then you need to enhance the question to include what the test strategy and characteristics are.  One way to improve this would be cut down the need for a second access.  Read the file, validate it and only insert the correct data into the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using HDD: 10000 mb * 200 / 40 mb/s = 50000 seconds to read all files from single hdd which is around 15 hours. If you are using SSD, it is around 5 hours. You can speed up by using multiple SSDs. Or creating virtual HDDs in ram memory and writing and reading from there. But most real thing - claster your environment to several pc or several SSDs.